# Greater than and less than not supported in location field of profile

Tags: support, profile-page

Back in the day, I was able to use the greater than and less than symbols in my "Location" profile field. It looks like they're being scrubbed now, but `&gt;` and `&lt;` don't yield the symbols either.  Has anyone figured out how to get these characters into the field?

**EDIT**

To add context to this, my location (yes, it's for fun) on SO and MSO is

> Milky Way>Solar System>Earth>North America>U.S.A>Ohio>Columbus

On ServerFault, it looks like this:

> Milky WaySolar SystemEarthNorth AmericaU.S.AOhioColumbus

I could figure out an alternative, but I'm feeling intellectually lazy at the moment, and I'm also curious about there being a way to accomplish this.

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of a location with < or > in the name

Comment: @Kyle it's just a text field. So people have fun with it.

Comment: It's probably being removed while trying to add it.

Comment: You could use periods and treat each as a subfield of the larger object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "`&gt;`"?

Comment: Second thing I tried.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the ">" was allowed, but isn't any longer.

So you created it OK on SO and it got transferred as-is to meta, but when you come to create it on SF the current code disallows it.

Comment: That about sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use-case here? Do you have an example location you want to use but can't?

Comment: What? You mean you've never heard of Milky Way>Solar System>Earth>North America>U.S.A>Ohio>Columbus?

Comment: (that's Michael's current Meta location)

Comment: Yeah, this location transferred from my SO account, but I'm unable to replicate it on ServerFault. :(